# Monitor (TV) shows as active even when turned off

Tags: windows-10, hdmi, tv, external-display

I have my primary PC with the monitor (DP) and TV (HDMI) connected.
When I turn off the TV, my PC till shows that TV as active display. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that "*is turned off*" is not the same as "*is disconnected*".

You are describing the normal behavior of **Windows**, it has nothing strange, if you have selected a PC-screen as primary device and your current energy plan or you manually turn off the screen, then that device will still be the primary device since it is not disconnected from power, it can be turned On again.